# Search string value from string array, if conditional then get sql database and display gridview or else show error

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have tried several ways to do this but some reason I am not able to correctly implement the If statement.

I am trying to acquire the `SelectedItem.Text` from `Drop Down List` and then search in the database for that row and store it in `DataSet` and then display it on a `GridView`. However, the database has 19 fixed columns with words, so if the user selects one drop down listing in the if statement the `DataSet` should get displayed on a `GridView` but if the data is not found in the database Else an error message should pop up saying "Data Not Found"

I have tried physically inputting the 19 fixed `columns` in an `Array` and using the following:

```
protected void SearchProductButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Producttext = SearchProductDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text; 
        string[] Producttext2 = 
        {
            "Chem",
            "Drill",
            "Elect",
            "Products",
            "Environmental",
            "Instrument",
            "Lab",
            "Lift",
            "Tools",
            "Repair",
            "Pipes",
            "Portable",
            "Power",
            "Steel",
            "Testing",
            "Tooling",
            "Tubes",
            "Valves",
            "Systems",
            "Consumables",
        };
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var daProduct = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Serial_No], [Material_No], [Product_Line], [Product_Description], [Size], [UOM], [Supplier_Price], [Price_Date], [Selling_Price] FROM [ProductDB] WHERE [Product_Line] = @Product_Line", con))
        {
            foreach (string x in Producttext2)
            {
                if (x.Contains(Producttext))                              
                {
                    daProduct.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Product_Line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Producttext;
                    DataSet dsProduct = new DataSet();
                    daProduct.Fill(dsProduct, "Product_Line");
                    SearchProductGridView.DataSource = dsProduct;
                    SearchProductGridView.DataBind();                        
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Not Found");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

In the SQL data I only have information filled for `Chem` & `Elect` so all the other ones should show an error but due to the `Foreach` the `x`value` is not clearing and stays at the first run value so it ends up skipping until it goes through the whole list.

I have modified the code after reading about the string to string array and then checking the `index` if it is `greater then -1` continue or `else` show the `error`.

Here's the code:

```
 protected void SearchProductButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Producttext = SearchProductDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text; 
        string[] Productarray = new string[20]; 
        Productarray[0] = "Chem";
        Productarray[1] = "Drill";
        Productarray[2] = "Elect";
        Productarray[3] = "Products";
        Productarray[4] = "Environmental";
        Productarray[5] = "Instrument";
        Productarray[6] = "Lab";
        Productarray[7] = "Lift";
        Productarray[8] = "Tools";
        Productarray[9] = "Repair";
        Productarray[10] = "Pipes";
        Productarray[11] = "Portable";
        Productarray[12] = "Power";
        Productarray[13] = "Steel";
        Productarray[14] = "Testing";
        Productarray[15] = "Tooling";
        Productarray[16] = "Tubes";
        Productarray[17] = "Valves";
        Productarray[18] = "Systems";
        Productarray[19] = "Consumables";

        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var daProduct = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Serial_No], [Material_No], [Product_Line], [Product_Description], [Size], [UOM], [Supplier_Price], [Price_Date], [Selling_Price] FROM [ProductDB] WHERE [Product_Line] = @Product_Line", con))
        {
            //foreach (string x in Producttext2)
            //{
            int index1 = Array.IndexOf(Productarray, Producttext);
                if (index1 !=-1)                             
                {
                    daProduct.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Product_Line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Producttext;
                    DataSet dsProduct = new DataSet();
                    daProduct.Fill(dsProduct, "Product_Line");
                    SearchProductGridView.DataSource = dsProduct;
                    SearchProductGridView.DataBind();                        

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Not Found");
                }
            //}

        }
    }
```

The problem with the second approach is that it never goes to the else statement no matter what I try.

**Edit:**

I have decided to approach my requirement in a different way, instead of using `Textbox` I have sorted to using `ComboBox` from `AJAX ToolKit`.

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="SearchMaterialComboBox" runat="server" 
        AutoCompleteMode="Append" AutoPostBack="false" CaseSensitive="false" 
        DataSourceID="ProductDBMaterialSqlDataSource" DataTextField="Material_No" 
        DataValueField="Material_No" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Height="20px" 
        MaxLength="10" RenderMode="Block" style="display: inline-block;" Width="285px">
    </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>**strong text**
```

**Code**:

```
protected void SearchMaterialButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //long Materialtextbox = Convert.ToInt64(SearchMaterialComboBox.Text);
        string Materialstr = SearchMaterialComboBox.Text;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var daMaterial = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Serial_No], [Material_No], [Product_Line], [Product_Description], [Size], [UOM], [Supplier_Price], [Price_Date], [Selling_Price] FROM [ProductDB] WHERE [Material_No] = @Material_No", con))
        {
            if (Materialstr != "")
            {
                daMaterial.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Material_No", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Materialstr;
                DataSet dsMaterial = new DataSet();
                daMaterial.Fill(dsMaterial, "Material_No");
                SearchProductGridView.DataSource = dsMaterial;
                SearchProductGridView.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

I believe the last post mentioned by @Patashu had a valid point by inserting in the `HasRows` a `value` of `0`, if it is not `0` then continue else show an error message. However, the current approach has the `AutoComplete` option which is neat comparing to the conventional `TextBox` approach.

Comment: You have a potential security hole in your this code:  `daProduct.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Product_Line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Producttext;`.  **Not** parameterizing your inputs is a great way to invite a [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Consider instead using:  `daProduct.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Line",  50);`

Comment: @Brian There is no SQL Injection possibility here.. they perform the same thing in the end. Onc just implicitly determines the DB type.. the other doesn't.

Comment: SearchProductDropDownList.items is Productarray ?

Comment: @Brian, I'm genuinely puzzled why you point out that "not parameterizing your inputs is a great way to invite a SQL Injection attack" by quoting the OP's code that is, self-evidently, adding a *parameter* to the `SelectCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

string match = Producttext2.FirstOrDefault((x) => x.Contains(Producttext));
if (match != null)
{
 // do stuff
}
else
{
 // error message
}
```

Method from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx

Comment: the method you have mentioned should work. But I think my logic is wrong. I am trying to do is to search for `Producttext` in the SQL DB by `SqlAdapter` and then post it on the `GridView`. What if the `Producttext` is not in the SQL DB, how can I show an error message "Data Not Found". 

My logic is flawed, `Producttext2` array has all the DB data, so every time the value will be true and never false.

Someone please shed some light.

Comment: If it's not in the DB, then your select will return 0 rows and you can act on that (by printing an error message). Am I missing something?